# SQL Server LDF file

Tags: sql-server

Is there any way to know the source of a LDF file. I have a giant LDF file but I dont know which database its coming from. I couldnt find any database with same name as LDF file. If I try to delete the file it gives me error that another program is using the file.

Please Help.

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the following and you should be able to track down the database associated with the file.  It will list all files associated with all your databases.

First create a temp table in master:

```
create table tempsystemfiles (
  fileid smallint,
  groupid smallint,
  size bigint,
  maxsize bigint,
  growth float,
  status int,
  perf int,
  name sysname,
  filename sysname,
  db_name sysname

);
```

Insert file information into the new table:

```
EXEC sp_Msforeachdb "use [?];insert master.dbo.tempsystemfiles select *,db_name() from sysfiles"
```

Then just select it out

```
select * from master.dbo.tempsystemfiles
```

Tada.

Comment: I've just edited my post - my original "solution" wasn't quite up to par.  Instead of having to go through each database and run TSQL this lets you do it on everything at once.

Comment: I just edited it once again to include the database name as part of the list and query, just to make it even easier.

Answer (score 3):

```
select db_name(database_id) as DBName, * 
from sys.master_files 
where physical_name = 'C:\path to your file\yourlogfile.ldf'
```

Comment: This also works - I was trying to give a solution that was overkill I'm sure... but it's what I use for reporting on files/sizes.